# Where is the oil produced from dry hopping?

Tags: beer, dry-hop

This might sound like a weird question, but there I go. From what I read and learnt "dry hopping adds fragile aromatic oils".

I wanted to know where do these oils settle in the carboy? On top of the beer? On the bottom? They are kind of mixed everywhere?

To me this seems important to know because if they are on the bottom, this means we better dry hop with a clean bottom!

Thanks.

Comment: You should have a clean everything anyway!

Comment: I was referring to the yeast cake :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The oils aren't produced from dry hopping, the oils are in the hop cones themselves.  Its the stuff in the lupulin glands of the cones that contains the oils.  I usually see the oil floating on top of the beer in the carboy.  But that likely isn't the only place the oil goes.  Its pretty sticky stuff and a lot of it sticks to the yeast, proteins, trub and the sides of your carboy, kegs and or bottles.

[image]

This picture is from the [Hops wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hops).  (I just wanted to see if I could do it right.)

Comment: Okay, thanks! So I can assume that even if I have a nice yeast cake at the bottom, dry hopping is completely possible :)